# error in mysql query statement in with order by query

Tags: mysql, jsp

i am using jsp page and i can easily done simple select query but as i am new bee i don't know how to write a query ..in which i am on the basis of selected check box i want to show sorted data ...for that i write following code

```
java.sql.ResultSet rs;
               out.println(sort.toString());
                 StringBuffer myquery=new StringBuffer("select * from message");

              if(count != 0)
              { 
               myquery.append(" ORDER BY ");

               myquery.append(sort);
                } 
                 rs=stmt.executeQuery(myquery.toString());
```

in above..**sort is the String that is contain column field** on which i wnat to sort...but it is giving me sql query statment error how can i solve or rewrite statements..

Comment: Try myquery.append("'" + sort "'"); + what is the error you get?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: what about out.println(myquery); after executing the query?

Comment: Paste the exact and complete error message and stack trace of the exception: this message is printed to help you and us diagnose the problem.